# Sublista Prolog

Tags: prolog

Quiero crear todas las sublistas de, por ejemplo, 3 elementos de una lista y además que estos elementos que contiene, antes de ser agregados, cumplan un predicado. 
Ejemplo:

> Lista: [11,12,9,8,7,6,5,3,2,4,15,16]
>   condicion: >5
>   sublista: [11,12,9]   [9,8,7]   [7,6,15]   [16,11,12]   [9,11,12]    .....

Todas las sublistas de 3 elementos que sean mayores a 5 por ejemplo.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
seleccionados(Lista,Sublista,Mayor):- findall(X,(member(X,Lista),X>Mayor),Sublista)
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido FSlog, ¿Podrías añadir el código que ya tengas echo/hayas intentado? Un saludo.

Comment: seleccionados(Lista,Sublista,Mayor):- findall(X,(member(X,Lista),X>Mayor),Sublista). se me ocurrio primero por ejemplo filtrar los q son mayores a ese numero , pero me falta crear todas las sublista de 3 elementos por ejemplo

Comment: @FSlog ¿has visto las respuestas o has encontrado un solución propia? En el primer caso, si alguna las preguntas resuelven tu problema, por favor, aceptala. Si has encontrado una solución propia, puedes ponerla como respuesta y aceptarla.

Answer (score 1):

Aplicar la condición es independiente de lo que hagas luego con el resultado. Se trata de aplicar un filtro a la lista y trabajar con una nueva lista, mediante `exclude/3`. Ahora la cuestión de obtener todas las sublistas de 3 elementos:

```
sublistas(Lista,NumElementos,Resultado) :-
    length(Resultado,NumElementos),
    append(Aux,_Der,Lista),
    append(_Izq,Resultado,Aux).
```

Todo junto:

```
condicion(N) :-
    N>5.

cosa_esta(Lista,N,Resultado):-
    exclude(Lista,condicion,ListaFiltrada),
    sublistas(ListaFiltrada,N,Resultado).
```

Y la prueba:

```
?- cosa_esta([11,12,9,8,7,6,5,3,2,4,15,16],3,R).
R = [11, 12, 9] ;
R = [12, 9, 8] ;
R = [9, 8, 7] ;
R = [8, 7, 6] ;
R = [7, 6, 15] ;
R = [6, 15, 16] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener todas las sublistas de una lista como si se tratase de su conjunto potencia, recursivamente. En el caso base, el conjunto potencia de una lista vacía `[]` es únicamente la lista vacía:

```
sublists([],[]).
```

Y el conjunto potencia de una lista con cabeza y cola `[X|Xs]` será las listas del conjunto potencia de la cola `Xs`, incluyendo y sin incluir la cabeza `X`:

```
sublists([_|Xs],Ys) :- sublists(Xs,Ys).
sublists([X|Xs],[X|Ys]) :- sublists(Xs,Ys).
```

Ahora puedes primero filtrar los elementos de la lista que satisfagan el predicado  mediante `include/3`, obtener el conjunto potencia de la lista filtrada mediante `sublists/2`, y quedarte únicamente con las soluciones del tamaño deseado mediante `length/2`:

```
sublists(Xs,Zs,S,P) :-
    include(P,Xs,Ys),
    length(Zs,S),
    sublists(Ys,Zs).
```

Por ejemplo, definimos los predicados `even/1` y `lt5/1` que verifican si un número es par o menor que 5, respectivamente:

```
even(X) :- 0 is X mod 2.
lt5(X) :- X < 5.
```

Y obtenemos todas las sublistas de números pares tomados de 2 en 2 de la lista `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`:

```
?- sublists([1,2,3,4,5,6],Xs,2,even).
Xs = [4, 6] ;
Xs = [2, 6] ;
Xs = [2, 4] ;
false.
```

O todas las sublistas de números menores que 5 tomados de 3 en 3:

```
?- sublists([1,2,3,4,5,6],Xs,3,lt5).
Xs = [2, 3, 4] ;
Xs = [1, 3, 4] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 4] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```